# Set Discounted Price for Related Product on Product Page

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to set the price of all related products on the products page to 10% less = 0.9

The goal is to provide a discount of all related products on the product page but when viewed as a product, give the normal price.

Overall, the idea is to provide incentive that generates up-selling of related products.

I am asking for two things here. **ONE**: change the product price for related products on the product page (10% off) and **TWO**: carry that discounted price into the cart and checkout when the related discounted product is added to cart from the product page.

I almost got the first part down, but the code I'm trying to get working is giving me an error saying:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
```

My code so far:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'related_product_price_discount', 100, 2 );
function related_product_price_discount( $price, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // make sure this is a related product on product page
    if( is_product() && $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ){
        $price = $price * 0.9;
    }
    // return related product price with discount
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd question is not a waste of time even if it's complicated, It's something advanced that requires some developer skills and development time to be spent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule in StackOverFlow is one question at the time, so I will answer only your first question, which is related to your code issue...

Note that the hook `woocommerce_get_price_html` is related to the displayed formatted price.

To avoid the error ***"Warning: A non-numeric value encountered"***, you will use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'related_product_price_discount', 100, 2 );
function related_product_price_discount( $price_html, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // make sure this is a related product on product page
    if( is_product() && $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ){
        $price_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) * 0.9 );
    }
    // return related product displayed discounted formatted price
    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I will ask a new question and link to this question. Your code works. Again, thank you.