# Woocommerce: Add text to price in cart but not to Related Products

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

I've added the text "kg*" after the price on the product page. However, it also adds the additional text to the price of the Related Products below. How do I exclude the price being added to the Related Products? I want to add the text only to the price of the product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hellblau_kg_nach_preis', 100, 2  );
function hellblau_kg_nach_preis($price){
    if( is_single() ) { 
        global $product;
        $weight = $product->get_weight();    
        return $price . '&nbsp;/ ' . $weight . '&nbsp;kg*';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

I've tried several things like `if( is_single() && ! RELATED-PRODUCTS )` without success.

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy, uncomplicated solution to this. `is_single()` _will_ be true if you are on a product detail page, the fact that this product might have related products assigned, doesn't change anything about that. The callback function for this hook gets the product class passed in a second parameter - but related products are not a specific sub-class of the product class, so that is nothing you could test for at this point either.

Comment: For the single product page, it could perhaps work, if you used `get_queried_object` to determine what the "main" product on this page is - and then check if the class instance passed in via the second parameter, is the same object (has the same post ID.) But that won't help if you need this distinction in any other place (not sure if your related products show up _only_ on the single product page.)

Comment: The text should ONLY be added to the price of the main product on all single product pages – nowhere else. I just thought that excluding the related products might solve the issue. `is_single` seems to be the wrong approach then. As of @Jarmo T's comment I've tried to add `if (! $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related')`within `is_single()` without success. Gotta say that I'm no programmer, but am capable of editing code a bit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prepend a text to single product price, but not to related products, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hellblau_kg_nach_preis', 100, 2  );
function hellblau_kg_nach_preis( $price_html, $product ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Only on single product pages and not on related products
    if( is_product() && $woocommerce_loop['name'] !== 'related' ) { 

        $weight = $product->get_weight(); 
        if ( $weight > 0 ) {
            $price_html .= '&nbsp;/ ' . $weight . '&nbsp;kg*';
        }
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Related: [Set Discounted Price for Related Product on Product Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112982/set-discounted-price-for-related-product-on-product-page/62114028#62114028)